# Sending a PHP variable with mySQL data back to javascript with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

The function I'm trying to code is a user inputs an ID integer into a box, the JS reads that box and uses JSON and Ajax to send that data to a PHP file. 
This file will take in the ID and run a MySQL query and returns that answer into a variable to be sent back to JavaScript and put into a table. 
I'm stuck as to how to get the PHP variable to send back to JavaScript or the format it returns in, any help would be appreciated.

```
$("#sid").click(function() {
    var selectID = document.getElementById("selectedID").value;//selects the ID it wants to
    var jsonSID = {"ID":selectID};
    var jsonSelectID = JSON.stringify(jsonSID);


    if(selectID=='')
        alert("Please select an ID to find");
    else{
        alert("goes to ajax")
        $.ajax ({
            type:"POST",
            url:"viewData.php",
            data: {selectData: jsonSelectID},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

                console.log(data.id);
                console.log(data.name);
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert("Didn't work, refresh and it should work");
            }

        });
    }

});
```

PHP File

```
         <?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "assignment5");
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
            $json = $_POST['selectData']; //Takes in the selected ID array
            $data = json_decode($json); //decodes the selected ID JSON array
            $selectedID = $data->ID; // this is the user selected ID

            $query = "SELECT * FROM datadump WHERE id = '$selectedID'"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
            $result = mysql_query($query);
                $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);
                echo json_encode($array);
   ?>
```

Comment: can you paste the output of `console.log(data);`

Comment: what is or isn't happening? *"I'm stuck"* doesn't tell us anything very meaningful. Also what if there is no $result? It's always easiest to write the part that works perfectly...it's the other contingencies that take the time to put together

Comment: It doesn't return any information, rather giving me an error about an unexpected '<' or just returning nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: mysql id deprecated better switch to mysqli or PDO

If you want to access only one or two variable variable you can sen in array and can retrive like this:.

```
success: function(data id){
  alert(data);
  alert(id);
},
```

And
if you want to retrieve multiple records you need something like this:
there is an error from fetching your php should be like this:

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM datadump WHERE id = '$selectedID'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  while($res = =mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $data[] = $res; 
  }
$res['data'] = $data;
echo json_encode($res);
```

After that send json object and in front end you need to split with `$.each function`